# PHP - interaction with google play market / google profile

Tags: php, android, google-play

*I really tried, but didn't find any matching answers, most of them are about Android dev/single app info, google play scraping etc.
Anyway, excuse me for possible duplicate.*

So, i can see the list of apps which are/were installed on my android device in google play interface ("My Apps"), so, is there any way to get that list in my PHP application, through some kind of API, maybe?

Question is not about tracking my own apps, but about tracking installs of any random app from the given list, on a specific device/google account

What i want to achieve:

1. User installs an app from the list
2. After some time/trigger, PHP backend checks, if this app is installed on user's device, and saves this info to DB

EDIT: It is meant, that user agreeds to share this information, to get some kind of reward, after installing an application.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: i would imagine that users, like me, would not want you to have this information.

Comment: @tim it is meant, that user agreeds to give this information to me, of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, which apps a user has chosen to add to their device is treated as confidential information, and a random person cannot just query that from a server. There are only two ways you could check this:

- Do it like advertising libraries do. They use the [Google Play referrer API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer) which finds out the referral code which prompted the install, and sends this back via the Ad library in the app.
- Or have your own app which is on the device and uses [`PackageManager.getInstalledApplications()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications(int)) to find out the applications on the device.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i'm gonna use the second way, it's much easier, cause i have an app already